# jq split array into two arrays

Tags: arrays, select, jq

I am new to jq and still trying to learn the basics of JSON, so please, excuse my lack of knowledge.
I find the tool amazingly fast, but I am struggling to get the results I need. I am sure it's possible as I've made it once by accident :(
I have input data, such as

```
[
  {"time":1499150456,"data":{"power":{"bus":3.88,"shunt":6.98,"load":3.89,"current":76.00},"light":{"light":21}}},
  {"time":1499150516,"data":{"power":{"bus":3.93,"shunt":1.67,"load":3.93,"current":16.20},"light":{"light":21}}},
  {"time":1499150576,"data":{"power":{"bus":3.92,"shunt":5.58,"load":3.93,"current":25.30},"light":{"light":21}}},
  {}
]
```

I want to extract it into something like

```
  [
   1499150456,
   1499150516,
   1499150576
  ]
  [
   76.00,
   16.20,
   25.30
  ]
```

What I used so far was:

```
cat inputFile.json | jq -C '.[] | select (length > 0)'
```

which outputs nice initial array without the last empty record.
Next, I am able to do

```
cat inputFile.json | jq -C '.[] | select (length > 0) | .time, .data.power.current'
```

The result is very close, but not exactly what I need.
I wanted to use map(.time) that I found in some example, but that resulted in an error - not sure how to use it and the examples did not work for me so far.

Answer (score 1):

The following filter produces the output exactly as described:

```
map(select(.time))
| map(.time), map(.data.power.current)
```

This is parsed as map(...) | ( map(...), map(...) ), thus resulting in a stream consisting of two JSON arrays.

Comment: No matter what I try, I always end up with "cannot index number with string"
I tried
`jq -r '.[] | select (length> 0) | map(select(.time))'`
but that is always producing the same error. Thanks to the length part it should skip the empty record, but still it does not work :(

Comment: Maybe you meant to write: 'map(select(length>0) | select(.time)) ` ? Or maybe: `.[] | select(length > 0 and .time)` ?

Comment: So I tried:
`jq -C '.[] | select (length > 0 and .time) | map(.time)'`
and 
`jq -C '.[] | select (length > 0) | map(select(.time))'`
and both ended up in `Cannot index number with string "time"`

Comment: @RobertKlauco - It makes no sense (in this context) to start with .[] and follow it with `map`. If you don't want the result as an array, then use .[] and forget the map.  Also, the original question has been answered. If you have another question, please create another SO question.

Answer (score -2):

first of all you can create a new json object. Before creting operation you should collect data in new array like this;

```
var timeData=[];
var currentData=[];
var mergedJsonData={};

var yourJsonDataLenght= JSON.yourJsonData.length;

for (infoIndex = 0; infoIndex < yourJsonDataLenght; infoIndex++) {

    timeData.push(JSON.yourJsonData.time[infoIndex]);
    currentData.push(JSON.yourJsonData.time[infoIndex].power.current);
}

mergedJsonData.push(timeData); 
mergedJsonData.push(currentData);
```